# Usar token para acessar uma plataforma

Tags: angularjs

Tenho uma aplicação web e estou acessando por um APP dessa maneira:

```
.controller('LoginCtrl', function($scope, $ionicPopup, $state, $http) {
    $scope.data = {};

    $scope.login = function() {
        $http.post('http://localhost:3000/login', $scope.data.session_email, $scope.data.session_password).success(function(data) {
            $state.go('improvements');
        }).error(function(data) {
            var alertPopup = $ionicPopup.alert({
                title: 'Login failed!',
                template: 'User/Password is Wrong'
            });
        });
    }
});
```

mas estou recebendo o seguinte erro:

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass):
  app/controllers/sessions_controller.rb:9:in `create'
```

Meu controller:

```
def create
    user = User.find_by(email: params[:session][:email].downcase)
    if user && user.authenticate(params[:session][:password]) && user.permission == true
      params[:session][:remember_me] == '1' ? remember(user) : forget(user)
      remember user
      redirect_to user
    elsif user && user.permission == false
      flash.now[:notpermission] = "You do not have a permission"
      render "new"
    else
      flash.now[:error] = "Invalid password or email"
      render "new"
    end
  end
```

Sei que preciso do token para acessar mas não sei como fazer isso…alguém pode me dar uma luz ?

Comment: em Qual módulo você está adicionando esse controller, esse módulo foi injetado na aplicação ??

Comment: esqueci de mencionar esse controller de baixo no caso é da aplicação web que eu quero acessar e o controller de cima é da APP

Comment: Olha, dificil dizer assim porém nas suas linhas códigos o método POST está errado, ( $http.post('http://localhost:3000/login', $scope.data.session_email, $scope.data.session_password)) você está passando 2 parametros e o post espera (URL, OBJETO) então ou você chama via GET e passa esses dois parametros na URL, ou passa um OBJETO JSON para o servidor

Comment: basta apenas trocar o get pelo post ?

Comment: Funcionou com o get perfeitamente obrigado.

Comment: Vou adicionar uma resposta para você oficializar, @archibald

Answer (score 1, accepted):

você está utilizando o método POST da forma errada,

```
$http.post('http://localhost:3000/login', $scope.data.session_email, $scope.data.session_password)
```

quando você informa que é um post, você pode utilizar 2 parâmetros, 'URL' e 'OJETO', do jeito que você está utilizando você está passando 3 parâmetros, a forma mais facil seria trocar para GET sua requisição e passar os parametros pela 'url', ou criar um OBJETO e passar os dois parâmetros.
$scope.data.session_email, 
$scope.data.session_password,

como propriedades desse objeto.

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente usando get. O log-in é feito com sucesso, mas ao acessar os dados da plataforma ja logado através da app ele me retorna a página inicial.. parece que não está persistindo a session, como posso resolver isso ?

Answer (score 2):

Talvez seja necessário autorizar o serviço `$http` a utilizar cookies (que é onde provavelmente a autenticação preserva o *bearer token*). Adicione o seguinte snippet à inicialização:

```
.config(function ($httpProvider) {
    $httpProvider.defaults.withCredentials = true;
});
```

Ou, alternativamente, especifique na chamada:

```
$http.get('url', { withCredentials: true})
```

Comment: dessa maneira eu recebo o erro XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:3000/login. A wildcard '*' cannot be used in the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header when the credentials flag is true. Origin 'http://192.168.1.36:8100' is therefore not allowed access.

Comment: @archibald os dois são realmente incompatíveis. Ou você usa asterisco para determinar que qualquer URL pode requisitar este endpoint via XHR, OU permite a passagem de cookies na requisição. Se você não possuir chamadas externas, remova o asterisco. Se possuir, liste os domínios que o utilizam um por um.